# How to set Hibernate validator in Tapestry?

Tags: hibernate, validation, tapestry

Hi I'm trying to copy the quick start skeleton of Tapestry 5.2 to Dynamic Web project in eclipse. In the quick start project I can generate the war file and run it in Tomcat but when I try to copy the project with the dependences to a new Dynamic Web project it throw a exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.validation.ValidatorFactory

I did copy the hibernate validator to web-inf/lib but tapestry can't find it.
How would I set it in Tapestry?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this has anything to do with tapestry or hibernate. You are missing [`javax.validation.ValidatorFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ValidatorFactory.html) on your classpath. This class is packaged with JEE6 which in your case is most likely provided by your Tomcat version but not by your Eclipse Web Project.

You will need to tell your Web Project to use JEE6 or add the jar manually yourself to the projects classpath.

Comment: Hi, but this problem happen just when I run it in tomcat.
Tomcat is already in my webproject.

Comment: I found this http://tapestry.apache.org/bean-validation.html and this is the reference implementation http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html but how to setup the Hibernate validator in Tapestry ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as in your question you mention it does work in Tomcat. Can you explain your complete setup? Do you run tomcat from within eclipse or do you run it standalone. When do you see the problem and when do you not see the problem? Still, your problem is that you do not have javax.validation.ValidatorFactory on your classpath in the failing situation. Tapestry, nor hibernate will load this for you as it should be provided by your JEE environment.

Comment: Hi, okay.. thank you for your answer... look I built a quickstart skeleton from Tapestry using maving. From it I can generate the war file and run/deploy it in Tomcat 7.. no problem till here.
Now, when I try to copy the quickstart example from the Maven project to eclipse dynamic web project it fails to deploy and run in tomcat.. it can't find ValidatorFactory.. I will try again from the start and I will see if it still happen and tell you. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that I found out, hope that it works for you.

(a) i am running tapestry from eclipse indigo.

(b) i obtained a copy of tapestry-bin-5.2.6.tar.gz

(c) stored all the files present in the lib folder of the above distribution in a folder (say foo) referenced by classpath

(d) then obtained the following files from various locations on the web an stored them in the same folder (foo)

(1) javax.validation-1.0.0.GA.jar (from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxvalidation100GAjar.htm)
(2) hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final and hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-4.2.0.Final
(from http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/)

(e) restarted eclipse - and it worked !